# cat a file's content, show non-printable chars as \xNN

Tags: cat, non-printing-characters

is there any linux command line tool to cat any file's content which may be mixed with UTF-8 string and non-printable chars, but also show  non-printable chars as \xNN?

such as `abc\xa1defg`,

PS: I don't need the two column output like xxd produces, or the the space separated output that `od` produces.

So far, the most close result is:  `od -t c FILE`

```
0000000   S   Q   L   i   t   e       f   o   r   m   a   t       3  \0
0000020 020  \0  \n   \t \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 001  \0  \0  \0 004
0000040  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 001  \0  \0  \0 004
```

But what I want is is like this

```
SQLite format 3\0\020\0
       \0\0.....
```

Found a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176111/how-to-dump-a-binary-file-as-a-c-c-string-literal

Comment: duplicate of [Bash command for replacing all non-printable characters?](https://superuser.com/questions/894727/bash-command-for-replacing-all-non-printable-characters). for example `tput setaf 2 | perl -pe 's/([^[:print:]\n])/sprintf("\\x%02x", ord($1))/ge'` would print `\x1b[32m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not perfect, but nearby:

```
hexdump -e '16 "%_c" "\n"' file.sqlite
```

`-e` specifies the output format, `16` = number of chars per line (iteration count), for `_c` see man page:

> Output characters in the default character set. Nonprinting characters
>   are displayed in three character, zero-padded octal, except for those
>   representable by standard escape notation (see above), which are
>   displayed as two character strings.

Output:

```
SQLite format 3\0
200\0001001\0@  \0\0006�\0\0\0\a
```

---

If you really want the output as described in your question, you'll have to roll your own programm. Here is a quick and easy solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
    while True:
        b = f.read(1)
        if not b:
            break
        c = ord(b)
        print(f'\\x{c:02x}' if (c < 32 or c > 126 and c < 161) else f'{c:c}', end='')
```

With a test file generated by this two liner

```
with open('test.dat','wb')as f:
    f.write(bytearray([i for i in range(256)]))
```

the output of `myhexdump test.dat` will be:

```
\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!